# Faster Way to copy files from one folder to another with Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, directory, path, copy

I have a code that work but wondering if there is a way that it will copy faster.
`FromPath` is on a shared folder, and `ToPath` is on my desktop.

```
Sub Update_Circulation_folder1()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        FromPath = Sheets("status").Range("H1").Value & "\"   ' DESKTOP

    ToPath = Sheets("status").Range("H2").Value & "\"     ' DESKTOP

    If Right(FromPath, 1) = "\" Then
        FromPath = Left(FromPath, Len(FromPath) - 1)
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) = "\" Then
        ToPath = Left(ToPath, Len(ToPath) - 1)

    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    FSO.CopyFolder source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: One line does the copy: `FSO.CopyFolder source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath`. You're asking how to speed it up?

Comment: You're *always* adding a backslash to the end of `FromPath` and `ToPath`, *then* checking if that's so, and if so, removing it. ......

Comment: To make I/O work faster, you need a faster I/O device. Copy from/to local hard drive (don't get a network involved), have a high-speed SSD. No code will make your hard drive's reader/writer head work faster.

Comment: @ BigBen  yes like to speed it up

Comment: You could early-bind it - what would move the binding of the FSO member calls from run-time to compile-time (which has its own very real advantages, but that will be a handful of milliseconds, unnoticeable), but the member call itself is I/O bound... if you need it to run faster, run it on a faster network.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if you can technically make the *copying* part any faster (as @BigBen metioned that's already a single line), but as I mention, you can skip checking for a `\` by using `Application.PathSeparator` to make sure it's a "legal" path style.

Also, I kind of tweaked it a little - doubt it actually affects speed - but since if the `FromPath` doesn't exist, you want to exit the sub, there's no need to create/check `ToPath`.

```
Sub Update_Circulation_folder1()
Dim FSO As Object
Dim FromPath As String
Dim ToPath As String
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    FromPath = Sheets("status").Range("H1").Value ' DESKTOP
    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then FromPath = FromPath & Application.PathSeparator
    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = True Then

        ToPath = Sheets("status").Range("H2").Value ' DESKTOP
        If Right(ToPath, 1) <> Application.PathSeparator Then ToPath = ToPath & Application.PathSeparator

        Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")
        FSO.CopyFolder Source:=FromPath, Destination:=ToPath
    Else
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
    End If
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Granted, it's somewhat trivial, but I thought worth mentioning since it uses `Application.PathSeparator`.

Answer (score 1):

I created a free Spreadsheet program that copies file really fast.
The page reference is: http://sam308.com/copy-multiple-files

**Copy Multiple Files**

Type of Program: Free Program

**System Requirements**

Any version of Microsoft Excel that supports Visual Basic for Applications (VBA).

This program will allow you copy multiple files from any source destination folder to any target destination folder.

There are two versions of the copy routine as shown in the image below:

- Copy Files via Excel
- Create Copy Batch File

[image]

The **Copy Files via Excel** copies the files via Excel using a macro routine. It is very useful for small to medium sized files and runs fast.

The **Create Copy Batch File** is intended to be used for huge files such as movie media and database files. It creates a batch (.bat) for copying the files.

**The reason is as follows:**

If you drag and drop, or copy and paste huge files from one folder to another, then the copying process is very slow. This is because Microsoft Windows caches each file in memory in case is to be dropped or pasted again into another location. When this happens, Microsoft Windows has to dump the cached file out of memory each time a new file is to be copied. This significantly slows down the copy process when copying multiple huge files at one time. Therefore, we use Microsoft Windows' xcopy command and create a batch file (.bat) that bypasses the memory cache and makes the copying process much faster. After the batch file is created, all you have to do is double-click on the batch file to perform the xcopy routine.

Below is the content of a sample batch file:

**Copy_Files.bat**

@echo off

echo Copying: [1/6] Home Video 1.mp4 & xcopy "D:\Media\Home Movies\Home Video 1.mp4" "E:\Media\Home Movies" /Q /J & echo.

echo Copying: [2/6] Home Video 2.mp4 & xcopy "D:\Media\Home Movies\Home Video 2.mp4" "E:\Media\Home Movies" /Q /J & echo.

echo Copying: [3/6] Home Video 3.mp4 & xcopy "D:\Media\Home Movies\Home Video 3.mp4" "E:\Media\Home Movies" /Q /J & echo.

echo Copying: [4/6] Home Video 4.mp4 & xcopy "D:\Media\Home Movies\Home Video 4.mp4" "E:\Media\Home Movies" /Q /J & echo.

echo Copying: [5/6] Home Video 5.mp4 & xcopy "D:\Media\Home Movies\Home Video 5.mp4" "E:\Media\Home Movies" /Q /J & echo.

echo Copying: [6/6] Home Video 6.mp4 & xcopy "D:\Media\Home Movies\Home Video 6.mp4" "E:\Media\Home Movies" /Q /J & echo.

Download

You can download the program here: [Copy_Multiple_Files.xls](http://sam308.com/download/Copy_Multiple_Files.xls)